# Is there a name for the school of thought behind writing tests?

Tags: testing, terminology

Essentially it is a branch of software engineering but SE itself is too large an umbrella.  I was curious if there was a title for the knowledge base that encompasses TDD, BDD, mocks/stubs/spys, unit tests vs. integration tests, code coverage, etc.

Comment: Software Testing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: TDD and BDD have nothing to do with software testing, they are about software design and software development.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: That's funny, since TDD has the word "test" in it. You can say that it's a subset of TDD, but you can't defend the statement that it has *nothing* to do with it.  My comment was a joke anyway; I despise these "arguing about terms" questions that ask for "the right word" without any interest in understanding the underlying concepts.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: In my experience, software testing is performed by a tester who is not involved in the development. This is to ensure that testing and development are completely independent activities (developers will usually be biased when testing their own code). In this sense, I think it is hard to classify TDD as testing, I would rather classify it as implementing against an executable specification.

Comment: @Giorgio: That's called Quality Assurance.  Or Verification and Validation, if you like.  The OP was asking about the overreaching term that encompasses all testing techniques.  There isn't one, as far as I know, other than perhaps software testing. Agile doesn't work because tests are written outside of the agile environment.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Ok. Then you have tests used for specification (TDD) and tests used for verification. In my shop we have the terms "development" for design and implementation, "testing" for verification (two different phases carried out by different people), so I automatically associate "testing" with the verification / validation phase. As a consequence, unit tests written by developers do not count as testing. But yes, the terminology may vary.

Comment: Honestly, aren't these just extensions of Defensive Programming?

Answer (score 2):

**Software quality assurance (SQA)** is probably a good term to use. A good discussion of of the different relevant practices may be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality_assurance).

**SQA** "examines and changes the software engineering process itself to reduce the number of faults that end up in the delivered software" ([Wikipedia_software_testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing#Software_quality_assurance_.28SQA.29)). It is concerned with improving the software development process to reduce the 'defect rate', and this includes practices such as BDD and TDD.

Comment: TDD and BDD have nothing to do with QA, they are about software design and software development.

Comment: I disagree. SQA "examines and changes the software engineering process itself to reduce the number of faults that end up in the delivered software" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing#Software_quality_assurance_.28SQA.29). It is concerned with improving the software development process to reduce the 'defect rate', and this includes practices such as BDD and TDD.

Comment: But TDD and BDD aren't about reducing the defect rate. They are about increasing the rate of (possible) change.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: That's funny, since unit testing is all about improving software quality and reliability.  TDD is partly about having the functionality of code covered by unit tests, so that you can refactor without breaking things.  If that increases the rate of change, it does it as a side-effect, and despite the fact that it provably takes longer to cover code with tests than it does just to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

You know that's a good question. I think that TDD and its ilk falls under the "Agile" umbrella. The concepts certainly were introduced by Agile proponents as means of providing a safety net that enables the other practices of Agile development.

Comment: No they were not. Unit testing was around before Agile was. Unit testing is the safety net you need to do any refactoring with confidence, whether you work in an Agile manner or not. Because Agile advocates YAGNI it also means you do a lot of refactoring when it turns out you do need something and you need to change your design for that. As a result Agile is a great proponent of unit testing, but that's all, they certainly didn't introduce it.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: Mike didn't say anything about unit testing. He talked about TDD. TDD and unit testing are completely orthogonal. TDD is a development practice that may or may not use unit tests in addition to integration tests, acceptance tests, system tests, functional tests, and a whole bunch of other kinds of tests. You can have unit tests without TDD and you can have TDD without unit tests. The two are completely independent. TDD was introduced by Kent Beck, very much in the context of what would later become "Agile".

Comment: @JörgWMittag: TDD is implemented with unit tests.  You can't defend the statement that it is completely independent, or even orthogonal.  I don't know where you got the idea that TDD is entirely about design; if it is, it's an incomplete technique.  Even Uncle Bob says that you can't grow a design from the ground up with TDD.

Comment: Please remember that TDD can stand both for Test Driven Design as well as for Test Driven Development. I took it as the latter... And as Robert says TDD and unit testing are in now way orthogonal.

Comment: @Giorgio: Yes, you can have unit test without doing anything else, but not the other way around. TDD (Test Driven **Design**) is built on TDD (Test Driven **Development**) and Test Driven Development cannot work without unit tests.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: you are wrong. You cannot, by its very definition, have test driven design without test driven development based on unit tests and all other automated tests built on top of that foundation.

Comment: Angels on the head of a pin.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I guess it has to do with different teams working differently and therefore using the same term for different things. For my shop TDD is not testing. The testers can implement automatic tests separately but these tests have nothing to do with unit tests written by developers (TDD). If other teams work differently they will use another terminology.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't get notification about these comments. Anyway, I did specifically say TDD originated with the Agile movement and it did. Of course there were unit tests before TDD. I never said it was an agile invention. But TDD is an agile concept.